# How can I run calculate and look after calculating process to remote Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I have a java program and I want to send task (jar) from it to remote
Hadoop. I need to pass special parameters to jar ofcourse.
If the calculating task just has ended java program must know this.

Can I do it through hadoop API?
Where can I get articles or someting also?

Comment: your question is very vague, and I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: I want say, then I need not only run calculation oh Hadoop, but also know when calculating is finished. Then I want launch other task, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop has some API's for this. so if you write Java code for a Hadoop Job, you can define the job characteristics like:

job.SetMapperClass(),
job.setReducerClass(),
job.setPartitionerClass(),
job.setInputPath(),
etc..

then you run your job, and you can wait for the job to finish by using

job.waitForCompletion(true)

Comment: This not exactly what i need.<br/>
I need pass any hadoop-module for Hadoop cluster. It something like this http://weblogs.java.net/blog/boneill42/archive/2011/12/19/programmatically-submitting-jobs-remote-hadoop-cluster .<br/> But I still don't understand, How can I get status calculating or will sure calculate is finished.

Comment: Are you talking about some custom code or 3rd party library(ies) you need in order for the Job to run correctly? You can use the DistributedCache mechanism (I think that's the name of the class), or simply hand copy the jar files into the classpath of the TaskTracker's on each of the servers.

Comment: And in terms of getting the status of the Job, there, there are API's for talking to the JobTracker, and getting the status of the Job. You can then use that to either get the Counters, or use different APIs to get the output file(s) from HDFS which should contain your results depending on how you wrote the Map/Reduce code.

Comment: Yes, Hadoop had deployed on remote server, and I know server IP address only. 
How can I get status of the Job via JobTracker API?
Where can I read about this?

Comment: Of Course I know username and password for hadoop too.